# My Visual Studio Code extension is not showing code properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello guys I am a student and a learner, new to Visual Studio code. I was working with java Scr ipt and whenever I was trying to save my code by pressing Ctrl+save button it was automatically indenting my code which show problems in my terminal can you please help me out!
Here is what i wrote before pressing Ctrl+save:

```
  return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <h1> Hello World this is my world i am the master of this world you all are my slaves! </h1>
        <FormControl >
        <InputLabel > Email a message... </InputLabel> 
        <Input value = { input }
        onChange = { event => setInput(event.target.value) }/>
        <Button disabled = {!input }
        color = "primary"
        variant = "contained"
        onClick = { sendMessage } > send </Button>  
        </FormControl>

{
  message.map(message => ( 
    <Message text={message}/>
  ))
} 
</div>);
  }
```

And here what it automatically does after pressing Ctrl+S:

```
    return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    h1 > Hello World this is my world i am the master of this world you all are my slaves! < /h1> <
    FormControl >
    <
    InputLabel > Email a message... < /InputLabel>  <
    Input value = { input }
    onChange = { event => setInput(event.target.value) }
    /> <
    Button disabled = {!input }
    color = "primary"
    variant = "contained"
    onClick = { sendMessage } > send < /Button>   <
    /FormControl>

    {
        message.map(message => ( <
            Message text = { message }
            />
        ))
    } <
    /div>);
}
```

Because this i am getting problems in my terminal as:

```
{
"resource": "/c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/fbmsg/fbmsg/src/App.js",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "1005",
"severity": 8,
"message": "'</' expected.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 41,
"startColumn": 24,
"endLineNumber": 41,
"endColumn": 24
```

}

Comment: Besides the poorly indented code, you should ask yourself why do you get wrong results in your terminal? It looks to me like your code is wrong to begin with and it cannot be compiled by `ts` in the first place. You should look at line 41 and see what's wrong there based on `"message": "'</' expected.",`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you'd like to know how to save your work in VS Code without the automatic formatting. If that's the case, there's a keyboard shortcut that saves the file without formatting.

**For Mac**:
Shift+K S

You can also open your command pallet with Shift+Cmd+P and search there for "Save without formatting" and it should tell you the correct shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Prettier** extension from the extension market of VS-Code. It makes code neat and pretty.

- You can further read about it [here](https://prettier.io)
- Other day to day VS-Code extensions can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdF2RcelRg0)